# Multi-user image editing

Tags: html, image, canvas, multi-user

I'm pretty new to HTML5, and want to know if this is possible.

I want to be able to create a canvas in which I can load an image in it, and then draw on it for other people to see, and allow them to make changes to it as well.

It doesn't have to be super complicated with lots of different tools, just basic stuff. I just want to be able to change the image every now and again.

Is this possible, and if so, can someone point me towards a tutorial of some sort?

Comment: If by 'Multi-user' you mean that two or more people could modify the image at the same time you will probably need node.js : http://nodejs.org/.
Buf I you just want the other to see it after the modification, a basic sql databas should make you happy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already know how to do non-image collaboration?

The way you do collaborative editing of any medium is pretty much the same.

The main difference between one medium and the next is the content of the updates (DOM elements vs. paint events). The other big thing you'll run into has nothing to do with the medium, but whether you want to use AJAX or WebSockets or what have you - this is a question more about the method through which you accomplish the collaboration.

The essential concept is (from the user's perspective):

- Submit my own changes
- Check periodically via AJAX to see if anyone else has made changes, or use WebSockets/long polling to be notified immediately of changes from others
- Update each person's view with the changes from other users
- Figure out a way to resolve conflicts if two changes are incompatible, if this applies to your problem
- Provide some way for users to "undo" things

Not to blow my own horn, but last year I wrote a collaborative scratch paper/brainstorming app called [cortex](http://cortex.karmanebula.com), and I [blogged about each commit and how I figured out how to do the realtime collaboration](http://karmanebula.com/cortex-commit-by-commit/?page=3). I did it in Rails using an AJAX approach, but the concepts I used for real-time collaboration are applicable to most any app that wants to take a similar approach. [This post](http://karmanebula.com/cortex-commit-by-commit/2012/7/1/added-sliding-animation-for-new-thought-boxes.html) includes a video simulating two users collaborating on the same page, and how soon/how often updates from one client are shown on the other client browswer.

cortex isn't the prettiest or most advanced thing in the world, but I think it's a good intro app to get the concepts down. It may not even be the best designed (it was my first collaboration app), but I use it nearly every day and it seems to work well enough.

Comment: good to meet you!  I see you have experience with sockets.  Do you have a recommendation on a particular socket lib you have experience with and why it's recommended?  I see socket.io and signalr are popular, but I was hoping to get the view of someone who has practical experience applying websockets.

Comment: I actually haven't done websockets, I just know that you can use them for this sort of thing as an alternative to AJAX, assuming your server and the browsers you want to support can do it